# How do I resize a cell in a table on a particular row without moving the borders of other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to resize some cells in a table on a particular row, but because the cell border is in line with the above or below cell, it changes the size of those cells as well.

How can I change the width of just that particular cell without affecting cells in the table that happen to have a border in line with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware you can without impacting the surrounding rows and columns.

If some of the neighbouring cells are empty you could merge them, then increase the font size (if needed) and change the alignment in the original as it then overlays/uses them...